# Why input file name disapear after adding a new one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In Javascript, I automatically add a new input file each time I choose a file ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qz5ek1op/)).

```
<script>
    function addNewInputFile()
    {
        document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML += '<input type="file" onchange="addNewInputFile()" />';
    }
</script>
<div id="inputs">
    <input type="file" onchange="addNewInputFile()" />
</div>
```

It's working except for the name of the file which disapears after the new input file has been appended. Do you know guys why the name disapear?

Comment: Presumably the values of the file inputs do not survive the round-trip through `innerHTML` (most probably for security reasons). You may want to try and save the values manually before updating the markup (if the browser allows you to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `+=` on a string, it doesn't append to that string, it makes a new string that is the sum of both of the previous strings, then stores that in the original variable.

So, by doing this, you're actually clearing and then re-filling the `innerHTML` of `#inputs`, causing the DOM to refresh, and the two inputs that you see after it is completed to be two *new* inputs, therefore discarding any file you gave the previous input.

I would recommend using jQuery's `append()` or `insertAfter()` methods to add elements to that div instead.

Comment: Correct! I tested it with jQuery and it works like a charm. Thank you!